# is there a way to write Firsestore security rules for non-ASCII collection names?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Many of my Firestore documents and collections are named in Arabic, but when I want to write security rules I noticed Arabic text is not accepted?
I need help on how to fix that?

I tried many types to write the Arabic collection names in the Security rules, but not accepted by Firebase and I couldn't any useful solution on the Internet for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here: I thought we'd covered this before, but can't find it - so I checked with the engineering team.*

The path segment in your rules definition may only contain `[A-Za-z0-9]` plus some special characters like `*` and `%`. For other characters, you can should use hex/URL escaping (using %).

So if I have a collection named één, I'd have a rule matching it as:

```
match /%C3%A9%C3%A9n/{docid} {
  allow read;
}
```

The `%C3%A9%C3%A9n` in there is the URL encoding of the collection name `één`, in this case gotten by doing `encodeURI('één')`.